# Circle not being drawn at the correct position pygame

Tags: python, pygame, draw

problem in my tic tac toe project once again, the circle isnt appearing where it should when I click a square, i tried multiple different coordinates but still cant figure it out, so if any of you know what to do then let me know, thanks.

```
import pygame, sys
import numpy as np
pygame.init()

screen_color = (28, 170, 156)
line_color = (23, 140, 135)
line_width = 9

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((550, 450))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tic Tac Toe")
screen.fill(screen_color)
board = np.zeros((3, 3))


def draw_lines():
    #1st horizontal
    pygame.draw.line(screen, line_color, (0, 135), (550, 135), line_width)
    #2nd horizontal
    pygame.draw.line(screen, line_color, (0, 300), (550, 300), line_width)
    #1st vertical
    pygame.draw.line(screen, line_color, (175, 0), (175, 450), line_width)
    #2nd vertical
    pygame.draw.line(screen, line_color, (370, 0), (370, 450), line_width)

def draw_figures():
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if board[row][col] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'cyan', (int(col * 550/3), int(row * 450/3)), 60, 10)
            

def mark_square(row, col, player):
    board[row][col] = player

def available_square(row, col):
    if board[row][col] == 0:
        return True

    else:
        return False

def is_board_full():
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if board[row][col] == 0:
                return False

print(is_board_full())
print(board)
draw_lines()

player = 1

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouseX = event.pos[0] #X coordinate
            mouseY = event.pos[1] #Y coordinate

            clicked_row = int(mouseY * 3 // 450)
            clicked_col = int(mouseX * 3 // 550)

            #print(clicked_col)
            #print(clicked_row)

            if available_square(clicked_row, clicked_col):
                if player == 1:
                    mark_square(clicked_row, clicked_col, 1)
                    player = 2
                
                elif player == 2:
                    mark_square(clicked_row, clicked_col, 2)
                    player = 1

                draw_figures()
                print(board)

    pygame.display.update()
```

(if there any other errors let me know too)
also let me know if getting the coordinates is trial and error or there is a specific way to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd argument of `pygame.draw.circle` is the center of the circle. Draw the circle at (col + 0.5) and (row + 0.5):

<s>`pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'cyan', (int(col * 550/3), int(row * 450/3)), 60, 10)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'cyan', (int((col + 0.5) * 550/3), int((row+0.5) * 450/3)), 60, 10)
```

Comment: can you help me with the cross, this coordinate is confusing as heck @Rabbid76

Comment: @DogeCoder use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object.  1. `rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 120, 120)` 2. `rect.center = (int((col + 0.5) * 550/3), int((row+0.5) * 450/3))`. now you can draw a line from `rect.topleft` to `rect.bottomright`and a line from `rect.bottomleft` to `rect.toprihgt`.

Comment: i added the rect but when i click the square it doesnt show the lines @Rabbid76

Comment: i did what u said for the rect but it doesnt work, i typed that exact code

Comment: @DogeCoder This code is not complete. Of course you have to call `pygame.draw.line`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the circle is centered on the grid and on on the middle of the squares.
You need to add an offset to the center like this:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'cyan', (int(col * 550/3 + x_offset), int(row * 450/3 + y_offset)), 60, 10)
```

I would also recommend you to create a variable called grid_width so that you don't need to have numbers like 550 or 450 everywhere in your programm.

Comment: ok thanks next time i will add a grid_width variable and a grid_height